# Regex capturing empty string along with the expected groups, want it to not to capture empty string

Tags: java, json

I built a regex to capture the value from the pattern, where pattern is to identify the json and fetch value from it. But along with the expected groups, it is also capturing the empty strings in the group.

Regex:
`(?<=((?i)(finInstKey)":)["]?)(.*?)(?=["|,|}])|(?<="((?i)finInstKey","value":)["]?)(.*?)(?=["|,|}])`

input:

1. {"finInstKey":500},{"name":"finInstKey","value":12345678900987654321}
2. {finInstKey":"500"},{"name":"finInstKey","value":"12345678900987654321"}

for these inputs, input 2 also captures the empty string along with the expected values.

actual output:

```
500
12345678900987654321

500

12345678900987654321
```

expected output:

```
500
12345678900987654321
500
12345678900987654321
```

As of now, I have handled it manually in the Java code, but it would be nice if regex won't capture the empty strings.
what changes should I make in the regex to get expected output.

**Mainly, I want this to replaceAll groups with masked value "****".**

My piece of code:

```
public class RegexTester {
    private static final String regex = "(?<=((?i)(%s)\":)[\"]?)(.*?)(?=[\"|,|}])|(?<=\"((?i)%s\",\"value\":)[\"]?)(.*?)(?=[\"|,|}])";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String field = "finInstKey";
        String input = "{\"finInstKey\":500},{\"name\":\"finInstKey\",\"value\":12345678900987654321}{finInstKey\":\"500\"},{\"name\":\"finInstKey\",\"value\":\"12345678900987654321\"}";
        try {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.format(regex, field, field));
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
//            System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("****"));
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is _finInstKey_ always a numeric value?

Comment: @Reilas no, it can be a string as well. and here I have provided finInstKey as static json key. In code, there will be a dynamic key name.

Comment: `(.*?)` is the same as `(.*)`

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8681) is about HTML instead of JSON, but it applies here none the less.

Answer (score 3):

It'd probably be easier using a JSON parsing library to parse JSON, instead of regex.
Try the `.fromJSON` method from https://github.com/google/gson

If you insist on using regex, maybe look into the `+` symbol in regex, it means "match one or more". Regex is pretty difficult to read when it gets complicated like you have there.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the regex to capture the json property values, and mask them and print the logs. I tried to do the same using jackson library but the performance was not close to the regex and patterns. So chose, regex for this task.

Comment: @ThakurSahab That decision will come back to bite you. For example, when you have to change your regex *again* to parse a slightly different object. Performance isn't everything, development speed matters as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `finInstKey` key is not enclosed in quotes leading to empty matches. By changing the pattern to `"finInstKey"` you will allow it to match this input and correctly extract the value.

Use it like

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String field = "finInstKey";
        String regex = "\"?" + field + "\"?(\\s*:\\s*\"?([^\",}]*)\"?|\",\"value\"\\s*:\\s*\"?([^\",}]*)\"?)";

        String input = "{\"finInstKey\":500},{\"name\":\"finInstKey\",\"value\":12345678900987654321}{finInstKey:\"500\"},{\"name\":\"finInstKey\",\"value\":\"12345678900987654321\"}";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
            } else {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the [code](https://onlinegdb.com/NBhjl06A1)

Comment: Thanks, But it is not giving me the expected output. In fact, this regex is not capturing all the expected groups.

Comment: @ThakurSahab I have updated the code with your input.

Comment: I have recently updated my question, and pasted my sample code. can you please take a look so that you may get familiar with what exactly I want to do.

Comment: @ThakurSahab The code is after your update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern.  The capture groups are 2 and 3.
It's not easy to determine the end of the value, considering a text value may contain any of the possible delimiters.
Assure that your data will conform; this implies that it's just a series of numbers.

```
(?si)(\"finInstKey\")\s*:\s*\"?(.+?)\b.+?\"name\"\s*:\s*\1\s*,\s*\"value\"\s*:\s*\"?(.+?)\b
```

Although, I recommend just using a *JSON* parsing module, *[Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson)* by *Google* works well.

You're *JSON* strings are actually arrays, so just place each within square brackets.

```json
[
  {
    "finInstKey": 500
  },
  {
    "name": "finInstKey",
    "value": 12345678900987654321
  }
]
```

Note that your second example has a missing quotation mark for the *finInstKey* key.

```json
[
  {
    "finInstKey": "500"
  },
  {
    "name": "finInstKey",
    "value": "12345678900987654321"
  }
]
```

With *Gson* you can utilize the *JsonParser* class to parse the *values*.

```java
String stringA = "[\n" +
    "  {\n" +
    "    \"finInstKey\": 500\n" +
    "  },\n" +
    "  {\n" +
    "    \"name\": \"finInstKey\",\n" +
    "    \"value\": 12345678900987654321\n" +
    "  }\n" +
    "]";
String stringB = "[\n" +
    "  {\n" +
    "    \"finInstKey\": \"500\"\n" +
    "  },\n" +
    "  {\n" +
    "    \"name\": \"finInstKey\",\n" +
    "    \"value\": \"12345678900987654321\"\n" +
    "  }\n" +
    "]";

JsonArray arrayA = JsonParser.parseString(stringA).getAsJsonArray();
JsonObject objectA1 = arrayA.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement elementA1 = objectA1.get("finInstKey");
int finInstKeyA = elementA1.getAsInt();
JsonObject objectA2 = arrayA.get(1).getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement elementA2 = objectA2.get("value");
BigInteger valueA = elementA2.getAsBigInteger();
System.out.println("finInstKeyA = " + finInstKeyA);
System.out.println("valueA = " + valueA);

JsonArray arrayB = JsonParser.parseString(stringB).getAsJsonArray();
JsonObject objectB1 = arrayB.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement elementB1 = objectB1.get("finInstKey");
String finInstKeyB = elementB1.getAsString();
JsonObject objectB2 = arrayB.get(1).getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement elementB2 = objectB2.get("value");
String valueB = elementB2.getAsString();
System.out.println("finInstKeyB = " + finInstKeyB);
System.out.println("valueB = " + valueB);
```

Output

```
finInstKeyA = 500
valueA = 12345678900987654321
finInstKeyB = 500
valueB = 12345678900987654321
```

Comment: I actually used jackson library before switching to Pattern and Matcher. The reason I chose to move to regex is the performance, regex performs way better than these libraries.

Comment: @ThakurSahab, I've updated the answer with a working pattern.

Comment: I have recently updated my question, and pasted my sample code. can you please take a look so that you may get familiar with what exactly I want to do.

Comment: @ThakurSahab, use `.+?` instead of `.*?`.

Comment: changing to (.+?) did helped me in not capturing the empty string but is capturing double quotes (") along with the value, like. "500

Comment: @ThakurSahab, try `((?!\").+?)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use not correct regexp.

```java
public static List<String> getData(String str, String field) {
    String regex = "(?:\"?" + field + "\"?:\"?(\\d+)\"?)|(?:\"name\":\""
            + field + "\",\"value\":\"?(\\d+)\"?)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        data.add(Optional.ofNullable(matcher.group(1))
                         .orElseGet(() -> matcher.group(2)));
    }

    return data;
}
```

*Output:*

```
500
12345678900987654321
500
12345678900987654321
```

***P.S.** I think parsing json with regexpis a strategically bad idea. I recommend you to use any Json parser (Jackson, Gson, ...)*